# How to display an Array list of Array list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix which consist of 2 array lists of array lists.
How can I display the final sparse matrix?

For example:

If my sparse matrix is of this kinde:

```
[ a b 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 c d 0 0 0 0 ]
[0 0 e f g 0 0 ]
[0 0 0 0 0 h 0 ]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 m ]
```

the element a is produced by two array lists which the one of them corresponds to the row and the second one to the  column.

For example the element a = 0 0, b = 0 1, c = 1,2 etc

Thank you in advance for your time;

Comment: What did you already try ?

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` overrides `Object#toString`.

As such, printing a nested `ArrayList` will print a human-readable representation of the list, flattened.

For instance, a `System.out.println` invocation passing your nested list will print:

`[[ a b 0 0 0 0 0],[0 c d 0 0 0 0 ],[0 0 e f g 0 0 ],[0 0 0 0 0 h 0 ],[0 0 0 0 0 0 m ]]`

If you want each list to be printed on top of each other (as in your representation of the matrix) you can simply iterate its `List` elements:

```
// Java --> 7
for (List<String> l :list) {
    System.out.println(l);
}

// Java 8
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
[a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, c, d, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, e, f, g, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, h, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, m]
```